# Connecting to remote mongo server

Tags: mongodb, port

I am having problems in connecting to an instance of mongodb running on a remote server. lets say i have a server **A** (123.45.67:27017) that runs a mongo db on port 27017. Then when i try to connect from my own machine **B** by typing:

`B$: mongo A:27017`

I will get an error

`Failed to connect to A:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused`

What i did for trouble shooting:

1. Made sure the port 27017 is open on the server A. Tested using nc -l 27017 and it works - i can type over to B.
2. Connected successfully to the database by using a ssh tunnel to bind the 27017 port to localhost: `ssh -f -L 27017:localhost:27017 myUserName@A sleep 10; mongo localhost:27017`

So in short, the database runs, the port is open and i can use the database when bound to local port. Anyone can help?

Comment: maybe your mongo server is only listening to localhost connections (which I belive is the default for security reason)

Comment: What do you get when your on server B and type `mongo --host <server A> --port 2701`  Security section is only for Authentication to the DB and if you have security `auth=true` then you need to add a user ad password to authenticate to the specific DB or Admin DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server probably isn't listening other than on localhost.

In `mongod.conf` (probably `/etc/mongod.conf`)

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # listen on all interfaces
```

Then restart the `mongod` service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize a remote connexion with mongo. By default you can access only from the same IP (localhost)

If I remember right, you should look inside the conf file
`sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf`
And look for a line call `security`. It should be uncommented and with the value enable